Long URL in author thanks footnote - spurious protect text added
I tried to move a very long URL which is being nicely line broken from the main body to the footnote in the author \thanks field, and the formatting has changed (printing lots of \protect) and I've no idea why. I can work around this with \textunderscore  but would be curious what is happening under the hood.


\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,anchorcolor=black, breaklinks]{hyperref} 

\title{}
\author{Someone Important\thanks{The line breaks in the footnote are fine when using 
\texttt{\textbackslash textunderscore}: 
\href{https://github.com/oliversheridanmethven/some_very_long_url_with_many_underscores}{\url{https://github.com/oliversheridanmethven/some\textunderscore very\textunderscore long\textunderscore url\textunderscore with\textunderscore many\textunderscore underscores}} 
but are horrible when using 
\texttt{\textbackslash \_}: 
\href{https://github.com/oliversheridanmethven/some_very_long_url_with_many_underscores}{\url{https://github.com/oliversheridanmethven/some\_very\_long\_url\_with\_many\_underscores}}
}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The line breaks in the main text are line broken nicely: \href{https://github.com/oliversheridanmethven/some_very_long_url_with_many_underscores}{\url{https://github.com/oliversheridanmethven/some\_very\_long\_url\_with\_many\_underscores}}.
\end{document}


Is there a reason you're using \href{url}{\url{url_with_command}} and not just \url{url} in place of the \href?  That seems to work for me.  Actually, I'm confused: the purpose of \url is to format and link a url.  Why have commands in it?  If you just want to format the url since href is doing the linking, you could have \href{url}{\nolinkurl{url}}.  But that's equivalent to \url{url}.

@Teepeemm No especially convincing reason, except that trying to just use href (as I am used to for clickable content like e.g. emails) it doesn't linebreak at all and spills into the margin, and then when I use just url I get the same problem still.

Off-topic: linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,anchorcolor=black may be expressed more succinctly as allcolors=black.

To typeset some URLs that contain TeX-special characters inside footnotes, it's (still) advisable to use the "defined URL"  or \urldef route. See the user guide of the url package for more information on how to use \urldef.

That said, for the particular URL at hand, the \urldef route isn't actually needed. I.e., one could simply write
\author{Anne Author\thanks{Bla bla \url{https://github.com/oliversheridanmethven/some_very_long_url_with_many_underscores}}}


\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xurl} % 'xurl' loads 'url' package automatically
%% create a "defined URL" macro:
\urldef\someurl\url{https://github.com/oliversheridanmethven/some_very_long_url_with_many_underscores}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black]{hyperref} 

\title{}
\author{Anne Author\thanks{Bla bla \someurl}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\setlength\textheight{2in} % just for this example
\maketitle

Hello\footnote{Bla bla \someurl}
\end{document}


Does the \urldef need to be in the preamble before the \begin{document}? That's pretty much the main thing about this is that seems a bit off.

@oliversm - Not sure why you appear to surmise that \urldef needs to be run in the preamble. You may see for yourself by running the \urldef directive after \begin{document} and any time before \maketitle.
